# Why can't I post asterisk or voip related questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I can see many questions on Stack Overflow related to what I have asked in my question, with answers. But the site tells me that you cannot ask [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886617/trunking-between-h323-and-sip).

Can anyone please answer my question?

Comment: Could you provide a couple of links to these questions that address trunking between H323 and SIP and are still deemed on-topic?

Comment: @Fred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876873/asterisk-authenciate-inbound-sip-invite-from-itsp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873047/transfer-not-working-over-h323-protocol-in-asterisk, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866363/agent-hangup-on-timeout,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829852/faxes-for-asterisk, just browse the newest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asterisk questions. None of them are about programming.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks, I voted to close all of these.

Comment: Continuation: Is the asterisk tag useful at all? Rarely a question which isn´t downvoted and/or closed.

Answer (score 15):

Your question is off-topic for at least two reasons:

1. It is not programming-related. You aren't writing any code, you aren't using any particular programming language, you aren't devising an algorithm, etc. etc. Rather, it sounds to me like you're setting up servers. Where did you see that listed in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as on-topic?

   Like Mike W told you in the comments to your original question, the fact that we have a tag for a technology does not mean that any question about that technology is on topic. We have a [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) tag, too, but just try asking how to format a bulleted list or use the mail merge feature and see how fast your question gets closed. The tag is intended for questions that relate to *programmatic automation* of Microsoft Word, not using or configuring it.
2. You do not ask a specific, answerable question. You are requesting "useful guidelines", which is not something that we can provide in an answer. One could write an entire book on how to set up servers to run a specific application—far too broad for a Stack Overflow answer.

   So even if this question *were* on topic, you would need to explain what you've tried so far, what exactly isn't working, and what the final result should look like. That is the only way that someone will have a prayer at helping you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a **direct quote** from the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about Stack Overflow:

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Further, the Questions FAQ states:

> 6. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>      for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>      for programming.
> 7. Questions on professional server, networking, or related
>      infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless
>      they directly involve programming or programming tools.

I think that's pretty clearly stated.